# Do composer writing groups exist?

Tags: composers

I was listening to a lecture series aimed at young (university-level) writers.  The instructor, who was himself a successful, well-known, published author, gave real-world advice to his students both about the craft of writing and the business of getting noticed and marketing their books.  In particular, he speaks frequently of his "writing group."

The writing group is a collection of 4-5 colleagues who agree to meet regularly, I gather about every 6-8 weeks.  The inner workings of the group vary, but each writer is expected to both generate new material to share with the group and give thoughtful feedback to the group on the work of others.

As a composer I've always wanted to find a group just like this.  I'd certainly be willing to give directed feedback to a colleague in exchange for his/her opinions of my work.  Before I reinvent the wheel and try to cobble something together, is there already a community of composers who function in a similar way?

Note that I'm not interested in *student* writing groups, rather groups aimed at practicing professional composers.

Comment: I think if you're aiming for the kind of writing group that your professor is in, with real life interactions and feedbacks, maybe instead of asking random people online, perhaps you'd have to find it in your social circle (your classmates, your colleagues, your friends, etc.)

Comment: @Divide1918 that would assume I'm an undergrad or grad student, which I'm not.  I am yet to find a circle of colleagues at a similar level as me among those people I know

Comment: There is a really good composer group at Berkley. You can join if you get accepted. There is also a good one at Julliard and the Peabody Institute. Depending on how there vetting system works there may be an interview and you may be required to play and discuss some of your work.

Comment: @Neil Meyer would you need to be enrolled there first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they don't, although other approaches could potentially yield results.  It might seem obvious, but have you tried meetup?  I'm not sure if it's still the hive of activity it once was, but there's a fair number of active groups on there.

https://www.meetup.com/topics/composers/

I'm assuming you're in the states, so it might be worth checking this list of composer associations and perhaps getting in touch to see what's available in your area:

https://composersforum.org/resources/organizations-supporting-composers-new-music/

There's also the National Association of Composers:

https://www.music-usa.org/nacusa/

Comment: this seems to be about as close as I'm going to find online.  These seem to have a much larger group size than I was looking for (meet-ups) but maybe it's time to start my own if it doesn't exist.  +1 for now at least

Comment: are you willing to edit your answer to lead with "No, there aren't..." Because that seems to be the case.  Meetups may be a reasonable place to start a search but if this definitively answered the question I would accept it.

Comment: Answer duly updated.

Comment: There is this, which is connected to this answer and looks promising...    https://composersforum.ning.com/